# Temp readings on 08 Macbook

Tags: mac, macbook, temperature

I just recently pulled out my old macbook, white from a long time ago to see if I can get it running just as a throw-a-round. It has a core duo, 2gb of ram (I may be putting 4 in -shrug-) and battery is completely shot. I'm learning how to use ubuntu since I've always wanted to, and now that I am setting it up I noticed that my TB0T temp is -127.0 celcius. Can anyone explain this to me, and what the other temp readings mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have different temperature sensors on your mac book by default.

here is a small list of commonly used sensors + the shortcut

```
TB0T Temperature Battery Temperature <-- that's the one we are looking for.

TC0D Temperature CPU0 Die Temperature

TC0P Temperature CPU VR area

TG0H Temperature GPU0 Heatsync

TG0P Temperature GPU0 Proximity

TG0T Temperature GPU0 Discrete Thermal Diode

Th0H Temperature NB/CPU/GPU HeatPipe 0 Proximity

Th1H Temperature NB/CPU/GPU HeatPipe 1 Proximity

TM0P Temperature FBDIMM Riser A incoming air Temp

Tm0P Temperature Misc Temperature (clock chip) Proximity

Ts0P Temperature Palm rest L

Ts1P Temperature Palm rest R
```

Since your battery is dead as you say it can be the reason that a wrong temperature is displayed here. For sure -127° C is not correct and I would not be concerned about it.

Comment: Just as an interesting side note: the value -127 can be seen in many non functioning temperature sensors, because (-127,128) is the maximum range of the 8 bit integer used to store the temperature values. Because 128º could be concerning as a temperature(my PC is burning!), the devs decided to default -127 if the temperature could not be read.